# Разобрать define логгера

Tags: c, логирование, макросы, define

Помогите разобраться в define'ах.

```
#define QUOTE_(WHAT) #WHAT
#define QUOTE(WHAT) QUOTE_(WHAT)
#define dbg(format, ...) printf("%s: "format, __FILE__":"QUOTE(__LINE__), ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

- В чем отличие одной решетки `#` от двух `##`?
- Как работает `QUOTE` / `QOUTE_`. Почему одного дефайна не достаточно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операторы `#` и `##` не имеют ничего общего вообще. Поэтому вопрос "в чем отличие" звучит странно.

1. Оператор `#` - это оператор преобразования параметра макроса в строковый литерал. Для параметра `P` `#P` превращается в `"A"`, где `A` - это аргумент, соответствующий параметру `P`.
2. Оператор `##` - это оператор конкатенации, т.е. соединения двух отдельных соседних лексем макроса в одну лексему. В макропроцессоре две соседние отдельные лексемы остаются отдельными лексемами, даже если между ними нет пробела, пока вы явно не попросите препроцессор объединить их в одну лексему при помощи `##`.

При выполнении подстановки параметров в определении макроса, каждый аргумент этого макроса сначала подвергается проверке на предмет того, не содержится ли в нем ссылок на другие макросы. Если таковые имеются, то сначала рекурсивным образом выполняется подстановка этих макросов в рамках отдельного аргумента, и только после завершения этого процесса результат вставляется "на свое место".

Однако (!) эта процедура рекурсивного анализа и подстановки в рамках аргумента *не выполняется* если соответствующий параметр в теле макроса соседствует с `#` или с `##`.

Именно эта последняя деталь является причиной того, почему макрос `QUOTE` реализован таким "двухэтажным" образом. Если бы мы просто наивно реализовали `QUOTE` как

```
#define QUOTE(WHAT) #WHAT
```

то вот в таком вот примере

```
#define V vasya

QUOTE(V)
```

результатом макроподстановки получилась бы строка `"V"`, но не строка `"vasya"`. Макро `QUOTE` получает на вход `V` в качестве значения для `WHAT` и, согласно вышеприведенному правилу (соседство с `#`) *не выполняет* никакого дальнейшего анализа значения `WHAT`, а просто сразу строит из него литерал `"V"`.

Если мы хотим, чтобы результатом макроподстановки получилась строка `"vasya"`, то нам надо дать макропроцессору возможность на каком-то этапе заменить `V` на `vasya`. Вот для этой цели такие макро делают двухэтажными

```
#define QUOTE_(WHAT) #WHAT
#define QUOTE(WHAT) QUOTE_(WHAT)
```

Сначала делается макроподстановка `QUOTE(V)`. Так как в определении этого макроса параметр `WHAT` не соседствует ни с `#`, ни c `##`, происходит замена `WHAT` на `vasya`. Далее рассматривается уже "вызов" макроса `QUOTE_(vasya)`, который и породит требуемый нам литерал `"vasya"`.

---

Использование `##`  в данном примере является нестандартным и не имеет никакого отношения к реальному назначению `##`. Это специфичное свойство GСС: в последовательности `, ## __VA_ARGS__` будет автоматически уничтожена запятая, если аргумент `__VA_ARGS__` пуст.